# Vaadin 14 Grid Component Column containing checkbox does not sort

Tags: grid, vaadin, vaadin-flow, columnsorting

I am using Vaadin 14 grid. This grid contains a number of columns. A few of them need to represent boolean values, hence we use a checkbox component inside that column. This is done by using `grid.addComponentColumn` method. The text related columns a just added using `grid.addColumn`

Now we want to enable multisort on the grid. By default the sorting indicators (up/down arrow) in the header are shown for the text based columns but not for the boolean values .

After adding sorting to the boolean column /component column (`addComponentColumn(...).setSortable(true)` the sorting indicators in the headers are shown, but the sorting itself is not performed when changing the sort direction (none / asc  / desc) using the arrows in the header.

How can I make this work?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you have custom logic for what's rendering in a column, then you also need to explicitly configure how sorting should be handled for that column.

If you're using in-memory data, then you do that using `Column.setComparator`. If you're using a backend data source, then you should instead use `Column.setSortProperty` and also ensure that the data provider actually considers the contents of `Query.getSortOrders`.

You can see an example of this in practice at https://cookbook.vaadin.com/sort-with-renderer.

Comment: Hi Leif, thanks for the answer. After a cup of coffee and some additional searching I also found the setComparator method. On https://vaadin.com/docs/v14/flow/components/tutorial-flow-grid.html#column-sorting this is also explained. I now got it working.